# IBM MQ get message with french symbols

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

How a message with french symbols can be decoded?
Example of message in MQ:

```
  "name":" ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻąćęłńóśźżƵƶÁáÂâÃãÀàÇçÉéÊêÍíÓóÔôÕõÚúÀÉÈÍÏÓÒÚÜÇ",
  "id":"2463"
```

When I receive a message from MQ there is:

```
"name":" ",
"id":"2463"
```

The filed "name" looks:
[image]

The code I use:

```java
    public static String getMessage() throws JMSException {
            String message = null;
            try {
                MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
                MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                gmo.options = MQGMO_ALL_MSGS_AVAILABLE | MQGMO_WAIT | MQGMO_PROPERTIES_AS_Q_DEF | MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQGMO_SYNCPOINT
                         | MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT;;
                cf.setHostName(HOST);
                cf.setChannel(CHANNEL);
                cf.setPort(PORT);
                cf.setQueueManager(QMN);
                cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);


                MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
                MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);


                MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue);


                connection.start();
                TextMessage receivedMessage = (TextMessage) receiver.receive();
                            byte[] bytes = receivedMessage.getText().getBytes("UTF-8");
                String s = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: What is the CCSID of the message?

Comment: For sending a message I set two properties:
tmo.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET, 1208);
 tmo.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_ENCODING, 546);

Comment: First of all you don't use the gmo variable in your code at all, so whatever you have set up there is not applied. It seems from the MQGMO_CONVERT option used, that you want CCSID conversion to be done by MQ, but that is not set correctly. You need to set it on the JMS destination. Try using this guide: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032130_.htm

Comment: But for us to be able to help, you would need to post the sending code too. By default MQ doesn't do any codepage conversion, so if conversion is not set on the channels or the receiver involved, you should get back the exact same codepage as the sender used.

Answer (score 0):

If the message is an instance of a `TextMessage` then its going to contain a UTF-16 conformant string and not a byte array.

You should, however, add in some guard logic to make sure:

```java
        Message receivedMessage = receiver.receive();
        if (receivedMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) receivedMessage;
            try {
                String text = textMessage.getText();
                ...
            } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
                ...
            }
        } else {
        // Not a TextMessage, maybe its a JMSBytesMessage, let's check 
           ...
        }
```

This is of course assuming that your producer app is generating text messages. So if it is a JMS app it should look something like:

```java
        Destination destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);

        JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
        logger.info("producer created");

        TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("
L'hôpital est près de l'hôtel");

        producer.send(destination, message);
```

Comment: Yes! It is an instance of a TextMessage. But when I try to System.out.print(textMessage.getText()); - I see the same incorrect message. Could you help with it?

Comment: If possible, can you do a string comparison of received message body with what you sent? like sentMessage.equals(textMessage.getText()). I am just guessing the console is displaying the output differently.

Comment: Maybe we need to look at how your text message is actually being generated. See my amended answer.